# How send REST calls and will get json back with the results?

Tags: javascript, json, rest, search

When someone write name and click on the search button then I want to show the search result into unordered list from external result.json file.I am just having a issue how to fetch result and show into the list.Please help me. I ll appreciate it.Below is my code.

index.html file

```
<form method="POST">
<label>Search</label>
<input type="text" id="Search" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
   <!-----Show result here-->
<ul>
 <li>

 </li>   
</ul>

<script>
const userAction = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('test.json', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: myBody, // string or object
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  });
  const myJson = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response
  // do something with myJson


}

</script>


result.json file
[
 {
     "id":1,
      "name":"John",
      "City":"Melbourne",
      "state":"VIC"

 }


]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For demonstration it was necessary to replace your source with placeholder.

```js
const list = document.getElementById('list');

const userAction = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
      fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(todos => {
    todos.forEach((todo) => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');

      li.innerHTML = `${todo.userId} ${todo.id} ${todo.title} ${todo.completed}`;

      list.appendChild(li);
    });
  })
}
```

```html
<form method="POST" onsubmit="userAction(event);">
  <label>Search</label>
  <input type="text" id="Search" />
  <input type="submit">
</form>

<!-----Show result here-->
<ul id="list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thanks iwonz. I just tested your code but I am getting this error:Fetch API cannot load file:///E:/test/test-app/test.json. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: It will be useful to read about CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If you want to make requests for a local file, you need a web server. Read about XAMPP or Denwer (for Windows). The easiest option is to use the Brackets editor which has a function "Live preview" which starts the local server and allows you to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just after the "  // do something with myJson"
you can do:

```
var myListElement = document.getElementById("myList");

myListElement.innerHTML = '<li>Id: '+ item.id +'</li>' + '<li>Name: '+ item.name +'</li>' + '<li> City: '+ item.City +'</li>' + '<li>State: '+ item.state +'</li>';
```

And Just After the:    
You can edit your  element like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
```